# PDO ODBC, one of several result sets causes php to crash

Tags: sql-server, iis-8.5, php-5.6, pdo-odbc

-Running PHP 5.6 on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2)

-Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 remotely via PDO, ODBC

-Issue isolated to one query, other queries function normally with expected results.

I am calling a stored procedure that returns eight result sets.  I write each result set to a CSV.  When I get to the third result set, php-cgi.exe crashes and I get a 500 error.

I have isolated the issue to this particular result set because if I skip the result set altogether using $stmt->nextRowset() everything works as expected.

```
    //execute sp, bind parameters year and period-defined above
    $StmtText = "{CALL PROCESS_PR (?, ?) }";
    $Stmt = $dbh->prepare($QueryText);
    $Stmt->bindParam(1, $PayYear, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $Stmt->bindParam(2, $PayPeriod, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $Stmt->execute();

    $file_out = fopen('c:\windows\temp\tmp_1.csv, 'w');
    $Result =  $Stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    foreach($Result as $row) { fputcsv($file_out,$row); }
    fclose($file_out);

    $Stmt->nextRowset();

    //this happens 8 times, fails on the third
```

I am not throwing any PHP errors, and advanced IIS logging doesn't suggest a whole lot.  I am struggling to determine what is crashing PHP.  I executed the stored procedure directly via SSMS and it executes successfully, and looking at the problematic result set, can't see anything out of the ordinary- no special characters, no long strings, etc.

I have also been down the road of confirming PHP memory limits are set appropriately, checking timeouts on both FastCGI and in php.ini, and verifying MVC++ 2012 is installed, both 32bit and 64bit.

Looking for any thoughts on how to track down php crashing on this one particular result set.  Thanks much.

**UPDATE:**   Laughing Vergil's answer below solved the issue.  The problematic result set had two fields with datatype varchar(max).  changing one of them to varchar(255) solved the problem.

Comment: Can you reorder the output for your statement (e.g. ORDER BY ... ASC)? If it fails again at the third loop, it is a problem on the php side, otherwise it is with the data.

Comment: Are there two text / varchar(max) / ntext / nvarchar(max) fields in the output? Something is tickling the back of my brain about this being a problem in some cases.  Just because, can you give us an output description - basically, what data type/size fields in sequence?

Comment: Additionally, do you know which individual statement causes the crash? If not, can you do the crazy debug thing of outputting information to a disk file between each line of code  (with open/append/close, so it will survive a crash) and find out?

Comment: BINGO!!!  there were two varchar(max) fields in the output.  changed one to archer(255) and it worked like a charm.  I never would have found that in a million years, thank you much